# Redirect one path to another while preserving the URL before the matching criteria

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect some path to another using .htaccess:

`RedirectMatch 301 /de/path(.*) /path$1`

What i really want to is to get rid of the "/de/" part (only when there is also /path following it) and redirect to /path. The rule above is working, however it redirects to the root of the domain.

How can i preserve the URL that is before /de/path and use it when redirecting to /path, i.e. :
`http://example.com/some/otherdirectory/de/path` to redirect to `http://example.com/some/otherdirectory/path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as simple as:

`RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/de/path $1/path`

If there is a need to also match what is after /de/path and append it to the new path:

`RedirectMatch 301 (.*)/de/path(.*) $1/path$2`